# Apache 2.4 Proxy AJP serve multiple domains with Tomcat 8

Tags: apache, tomcat, configuration, proxy, ajp

I developed three Spring based web applications were deployed on my Tomcat 8 server. I can access them in LAN by access as:

```
http://localhost:8080/webapps1
http://localhost:8080/webapps2
http://localhost:8080/webapps3
```

which works fine for me.

Tomcat AJP connector was configured as:

```
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

Now I tried to publish all the three apps into Internet by using apache 2.4 proxy configure through AJP connector

I also have three FQDN were registered such as:

```
www.thss.domain1.com.au
www.stoa.domain2.com.au
ozssc.stoa.domain2.com.au
```

I tested those three FQDN with check-host.net, they all works fine.

Now I will configure my apache 2.4 by using proxy virtual host setting, configure file name as: apache-serviceproxy.conf in /Library/Server/Web/Config/Proxy

```
......
listen 10.0.1.100:80
......
<VirtualHost 10.0.1.100:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ServerName www.thss.domain1.com.au
  ServerAlias thss.domain1.com.au
  ServerAdmin admin@domain1.com.au
  ProxyPass / ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/webapps1/
  ProxyPassReverse / ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/webapps1/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 10.0.1.100:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ServerName www.stoa.domain2.com.au
  ServerAlias stoa.domain2.com.au
  ServerAdmin admin@domain1.com.au
  ProxyPass / ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/webapps2/
  ProxyPassReverse / ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/webapps2/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 10.0.1.100:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ServerName ozssc.stoa.domain2.com.au
  ServerAdmin admin@domain1.com.au
  ProxyPass / ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/webapps3/
  ProxyPassReverse / ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/webapps3/
</VirtualHost>
```

Please note, FQDN 2 and 3 working in same domain (domain2.com.au) and FQDN 1 working in other domain (domain1.com.au)

I tested over internet by using net renderer.com, FQDN 1 www.thss.domain1.com.au is working beautifully, but FQDN 2 and 3 not working well, I check with my tomcat access log I found some thing is very interesting.

details as:

When I access my first FQDN (www.thss.domain1.com.au) from Internet the request pass through: Router -> Apache 2.4 (port 80) -> AJP connector (8009) -> Tomcat 8.0.28 successfully, all pages working well.

Tomcat access log shows:

```
58.106.1.75 - - [01/Nov/2015:09:37:40 +1100] "GET /webapps1/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2616
58.106.1.75 - - [01/Nov/2015:09:37:40 +1100] "GET /webapps1/css/thss_layout.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1405
58.106.1.75 - - [01/Nov/2015:09:37:40 +1100] "GET /webapps1/js/dojo-release-1.8.6/dojo/dojo.js HTTP/1.1" 200 158637
```

Such means, html request, inclusive css/js file request all using single context path /webapps1, which is perfect.

But when I request my FQDN 2 (www.stoa.domain2.com.au) and 3 (ozssc.stoa.domain2.com.au), it only first request come with correct context path such as: /webapps2 any next request on inclusive css and js or image file were double context path such as: /webapps2/webapps2, as it is not well formatted context path, Tomcat response 404 error. As result: All FQDN 2 and 3 pages with out css/js/image support, only display some plain text.

Access log shows:

```
148.251.45.185 - - [01/Nov/2015:08:58:59 +1100] "GET /webapps2/ HTTP/1.1" 200 19098
148.251.45.185 - - [01/Nov/2015:08:59:00 +1100] "GET /webapps2/webapps2/dojo-release-1.10.4/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1158
148.251.45.185 - - [01/Nov/2015:08:59:01 +1100] "GET /webapps2/webapps2/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1088
148.251.45.185 - - [01/Nov/2015:08:59:02 +1100] "GET /webapps2/webapps2/images/icons/search33.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1112
```

My questions is: How I can configure my proxy with AJP without append that duplicated context path in the front of request from apache 2.4 to tomcat through AJP connector?

Any advice are welcome!

Have a good weekend! Mate

Comment: Thanks, I had a good laugh: 'have a nice weekend: mate !' ... But if you do run in protected mode ;-)

Comment: Ha. Protected Mode??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't change the context path in the ProxyPass directive. There are many, many ways to shoot yourself in the foot when you do this.

At a guess, the links on your pages are absolute so they include the context path. When the client then requests these, the ProxyPass directive adds the context path again.

The simplest solution is to configure Tomcat for virtual hosting and deploy each of your applications as the ROOT web app in its own virtual host.

Comment: Hi. Mark. Thank you very much! I had did what you said to configure tomcat by using tomcat virtual hosting setting to enable all my three apps on the internet. But as I will use SSL later to enable our customer to sign in their account, I will still prefer go Apache ->AJP->tomcat way, as apache is much better in using SSL than tomcat.